# For Loop Algorithm ( number of operations )?

Tags: c++, algorithm, operation

Please can someone help me in how to count number of operations for (for nested loop) like this one:

```
for(int c=0; c<10; c++){
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
       for(int r=0; r<n; r++)
           cout<<j;
      cout<<endl;
      }
```

Comment: n*n*10. Where's the point in this??

Comment: is that an interview question? Probably someone playing smart with the fact that there are no braces arround the inner for statement so endl will only be printed n*10 times. Still you have to define what do you mean by operation etc

Comment: @izomorphius Indeed, does incrementing the counters count as an operation?

Answer (score 1):

That would be (roughly proportional to) `10n2`.

Not exactly, depending on how you define operations. For example, the output of the newline only happens `10` times.

So, if your operation was a `cout` statement, it would be `10n2 + 10`.

Answer (score 1):

n*n*10 + 10, if both `std::cout << j` and `std::cout << endl;` count as a separate operation.

Answer (score 1):

correct indentation would be:

```
for(int c=0; c<10; c++) {
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
        for(int r=0; r<n; r++)
            cout<<j;
    cout<<endl;
}
```

adding the missing braces you get:

```
for(int c=0; c<10; c++) {
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
        for(int r=0; r<n; r++) {
            cout<<j;
        }
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

now you can clearly see how many times it will print:

```
(10 * n * n) + (10)
```

Comment: I think what you have do is just to determine the big(O) for this code which is O(n^2).
what about C++ , j++ and r++?
also,c=0,j=0 and r=0 each of these statements we can consider it as an operation,so as in the loop how I can evaluate the number of iteration for each one?

Comment: @user1735329 you need to first define **operation** for that but it's highly architecture dependant. `r++` might correspond to one machine level instruction in one machine and three instructions in another. it is usually not required, why exactly do you need it for?

Answer (score 0):

The number of iterations is

```
  10 * n * n
```